# Refresh The New Content With AJAX

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

In this example I want when the button with ID "PostCommentsButton" is pressed this ContentTemplate to be triggered and to iterate all again in ListView with ID "CommentListView". But this didn't work here. What I miss ?

In this example I take the new text from textfield and in code behind I put this new content from textfield with ado.net and I save this new content in database. The problem is that when the button in UpdatePanel is pressed the new information didn't come in the list with the other content. It comes only if I restart the page. I want ListView in UpdatePanel to be iterated again to take this new content from the textfield with AJAX when the button is pressed.  What should I do ?

aspx code:

```
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="PostCommentsButton" />
                    </Triggers>
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:ListView ID="CommentListView" runat="server" DataSource= '<%# Eval("Comments") %>'>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <div class="postComments">
                                    <span class="authorComment"><%# Eval("Author") %></span>
                                    :
                                    <span class="commentContent"><%# Eval("Message") %></span>
                                </div>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:ListView>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

code behind :

```
   protected void PostsListView_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        //commandName is for recognize the clicked button
        if (e.CommandName == "postComment")
        {
            //get the comment from textbox from current listview iteration
            BlogProfileEntities blogProfile = new BlogProfileEntities();
            var commentBox = e.Item.FindControl("AddCommentTextbox") as TextBox;
            var hiddenFieldPostID = e.Item.FindControl("CurrentPostIDHiddenField") as HiddenField;
            string text = commentBox.Text;
            var postID = hiddenFieldPostID.Value;
            Comment newComment = new Comment()
            {
                Message = text,
                PostID = int.Parse(postID),
                Author = Membership.GetUser().UserName
            };

            blogProfile.Comments.Add(newComment);
            blogProfile.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Code behind code behind code behind code...

Answer (score 0):

I dont see a text box in your example.  If the text box is not in the update panel that gets called when the list view post back fires, I dont think you'll get the current value.  I would suspect that if you put a break point on your commentBox variable, you would see it comes back as Nothing.  If this isn't your full code, post everything.